React Project Output Issues
I have been referencing a youtube video for creating an e-commerce webapage however even after following each step his project appears normal however mine appears large, when i shrink the page to 80% then it appears like his, so is the problem my device or something in the code.
The video I am referencing- https://youtu.be/y99YgaQjgx4?si=RqtgCexvK9jzj5AK, the page i am talking about is at 54:15
My screen at 100% zoom
My screen at 80% zoom
I tried editing it at css but it doesnt work


Is the problem my device or something in the code?

Assuming you've correctly copied and applied all the tutorial code and styling then my best guess is that you are simply using a smaller screen than the author of the video uses and there's some CSS rules enforcing minimal dimensions of UI elements so the UI overflows on your smaller screen.
Instead of manually scaling your browser window to zoom in/out, you can use your browser's devtools to test responsive design in different resolutions.
For example, in the Chrome devtools you can enable the "device toolbar" and select the "Responsive" device and set the width and height to match a small screen size:

Compare/contrast this against a larger resolution

In the larger screen resolution more of the rendered content is available on the screen and there is side-padding.
